# Selected listbox item not storing and returning null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to store the value of the user's selected value to the controller. But the supposedly selected value keeps coming back as null. The value is not even storing, how do I get the selected value to store? I'm not sure if I'm missing anything or what I'm doing wrong.

Model:
In my model I created the content of the listbox and store value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PAM_Dashboard_Project.Models


{

    public class Vaults
    {

        public string Envs { get; set; }
    }


    public enum Envs
    {
        RTPprod,
        OMA,
        BG1,
        BG2,
        Cloud,
        Workstation,
        QA


}
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-controller="CyberArk" asp-action="CyberArk" method="post" role="form" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to execute this script?');" id="form1" style="display:none;">
            <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

                @* Form 1 *@

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                                Vault Status
                            </a>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                                </div>
                                @model PAM_Dashboard_Project.Models.Vaults
                                @Html.DropDownList("Environments",
                         new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Envs))),
                                "Select Enivronment" ,
                                new {@class = "form-control"})

                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Controller:
Disregard anything before [HttpPost], as the material above is unrelated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PAM_Dashboard_Project.Models;

namespace PAM_Dashboard_Project.Controllers
{
    public class CyberArkController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult CyberArk()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]

     public string CyberArk(Vaults newVault)
        {
            string SelectedValue = newVault.Envs;

            return(SelectedValue);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your generating a dropdownlist for a property named `Environments` but your model does not even contain a property with that name. I assume you want to bind to `Envs`, therefore it would be `@Html.DropDownList("Envs", ...)`, but in any case, your property should be `public Envs Envs { get; set; }` (not `string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just edit

```
@Html.DropDownList("Envs", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Envs))), "Select Enivronment" , new {@class = "form-control"})
```

You should set the name of generated select tag to be the same of name of parameters of the action (in your case **Envs**)